# Cumulative Returns Calculation Giving Astronomical Result

Tags: pandas, quantitative-finance, back-testing

I am backtesting a strategy and the cumulative returns get absolutely ridiculous as time goes on.

Here is how I am calculating cumulative return:

```
pred['cumulative'] = pred.position.add(1).cumprod() - 1
```

Where position is the pct. return series of the strategy.

```
pred.position.head()

date
2015-12-30    0.065293
2016-01-04    0.039952
2016-01-06   -0.050252
2016-01-07   -0.009129
2016-01-08    0.018204
Name: position, dtype: float64
```

As you can see the cumulative returns are off the chart:

[image: Cumulative Returns Plot]

The returns however remain relatively constant:

[image: Returns Plot]

Any help trouble shooting what I am doing wrong would be useful!

Comment: Are these daily returns? If so, it checks out. For example, compound value with ~0.01 daily rate over 8 years would become an enormous number.

Comment: I suppose my question would be is the hockey stick just a factor of cumulative returns or would that indicate that something changed in the return series

Comment: It's just a factor of cumulative returns. If you looked at just the period up to 2022-04-04 you'd see the curve has a similar shape, it's just the scale will be changed. As @cottontail pointed out, `1.01^(260*8) = 973,772,415.43` (assuming 52 5-day trading weeks)

Comment: You could try cumsum() instead of cumprod(). And the size of the transaction is adjusted based on the value of the asset at the time of opening. I did it in the following way: I found the absolute maximum of the asset in history and the size of transaction will be: (absolute maximum/ price of the asset at the time of opening) * (result of the transaction(return)).

Comment: seems to have a normal behaviour. What is the mean and average over all values and how many positive and negtive values do you have... and show may be the values in April  till June 2023, there seems to happen something different.

Comment: Are the units here correct? You describe this as a percentage return, but the code is treating the number as a proportion, not a percentage, which makes your returns 100x bigger. Does `2015-12-30    0.065293` represent a 6.5% return, or a 0.065% return?